# Writing a pickle file to an s3 bucket in AWS

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write a pandas dataframe as a pickle file into an s3 bucket in AWS. I know that I can write dataframe `new_df` as a csv to an s3 bucket as follows:

```
bucket='mybucket'
key='path'

csv_buffer = StringIO()
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

new_df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
s3_resource.Object(bucket,path).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

I've tried using the same code as above with `to_pickle()` but with no success.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found the solution, need to call BytesIO into the buffer for pickle files instead of StringIO (which are for CSV files).

```
import io
import boto3

pickle_buffer = io.BytesIO()
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

new_df.to_pickle(pickle_buffer)
s3_resource.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=pickle_buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: I get the error: `ValueError: Unrecognized compression type: infer` when using this code

Comment: I get the error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: if you are getting ValueError: infer, change the compression to None. it's set by default to infer. 
df.to_pickle(buffer_pickle, compression=None)

Comment: using this method caused `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` error for me as well, I used `buffer = pickle.dumps(df)` and then used buffer as the Body for s3 put

Answer (score 37):

Further to you answer, you don't need to convert to csv. 
pickle.dumps method returns a byte obj. see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

```
import boto3
import pickle

bucket='your_bucket_name'
key='your_pickle_filename.pkl'
pickle_byte_obj = pickle.dumps([var1, var2, ..., varn]) 
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket,key).put(Body=pickle_byte_obj)
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion, how to use this with a pandas-Dataframe? i tried pickle_byte_obj = df.to_pickle(None).encode() but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: ```import s3fs``` and then you can ```df.to_csv('s3://bucket/path/fn.csv')```

Answer (score 9):

this worked for me with pandas 0.23.4 and boto3 1.7.80 :

```
bucket='your_bucket_name'
key='your_pickle_filename.pkl'
new_df.to_pickle(key)
s3_resource.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=open(key, 'rb'))
```

Comment: I think you mean to put `key` instead of `path`, so that it reads:  `s3_resource.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=open(key, 'rb'))`, right?  Also, this worked for me and did not throw a `I/O operation on a closed file` error once I replaced 'path'. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This solution (using s3fs) worked perfectly and elegantly for my team:

```
import s3fs
from pickle import dump

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

bucket = 'bucket1'
key = 'your_pickle_filename.pkl'

dump(data, fs.open(f's3://{bucket}/{key}', 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds some clarification to a previous answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3

# make df
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1:': [1,2,3]})

# bucket name
str_bucket = 'bucket_name'
# filename
str_key_file = 'df.pkl'
# bucket path
str_key_bucket = dir_1/dir2/{str_key_file}'

# write df to local pkl file
df.to_pickle(str_key_file)

# put object into s3
boto3.resource('s3').Object(str_bucket, str_key_bucket).put(Body=open(str_key_file, 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the just-released book 'Time Series Analysis with Python' by Tarek Atwan, I learned this method:

```
            import pandas as pd
            df = pd.DataFrame(...)

            df.to_pickle('s3://mybucket/pklfile.bz2',
                   storage_options={
                       'key': AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                       'secret': AWS_SECRET_KEY
                   }
            )
```

which I believe is more pythonic.

Comment: Do you have a link to the book? Are you affiliated at all?

Comment: No I am not affiliated with Amazon or the author. Here is a link on Amazon.  https://www.amazon.com/Time-Analysis-Python-Cookbook-exploratory/dp/1801075549/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2FVKJSGSW2RVL&keywords=tarek+atwan&qid=1665051468&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjAwIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=tarek+atwa%2Caps%2C157&sr=8-1

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best solution - just upgrade pandas and also install s3fs:

```
pip install s3fs==2022.8.2
pip install install pandas==1.1.5


bucket,key='mybucket','path'


df.to_pickle(f"{bucket}{key}.pkl.gz", compression='gzip')
```